# c# JsonResult RecursionLimit exceeded

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, recursion

I am building an object for the viewer but it is getting an 500 internal server error, I had to add application end request in the global to see the real error.

> My result only have 73 objects so I dont understand why I am getting this error

IE Error:

```
HTTP500: SERVER ERROR - The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
(XHR)POST - http://localhost:52312/DiseasesPicklist/GetPicklistItems
```

VS

```
?this.Context.AllErrors
{System.Exception[1]}
    [0]: {"RecursionLimit exceeded."}
```

Code

```
protected JsonResult ExecutePostAjaxAction(Func<object> action, string customMessage = null)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return Json(new PostAjaxActionResult
        {
            Success = false,
            ErrorMessage = string.Join(", ", ModelState.Values.Where(v => v.Errors.Any()).SelectMany(v => v.Errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage)))
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    try
    {
        var result = action();
        var message = customMessage ?? "";
        return Json(new PostAjaxActionResult { Success = true, Result = result, SuccessMessage = message}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LogHelper.LogException(e);
        return Json(new PostAjaxActionResult { Success = false, ErrorMessage = e.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know which line of code is throwing the exception?

Comment: I dont know what line is throwing the exception.

Comment: Json(PostAjaxActionResult will create a json with many many fields. Can you use a custom class instead?

Comment: I guess I can but would I get the same error?

Comment: The line that is throwing the exception should be in your stack trace of the "real error."

Comment: What is returned from your `action`?  I suspect that you have something such as a parent object with a `child` property, which contains a child object with a `parent` property pointing back to the first object.  As .NET is trying to JSON serialise that structure, it is infinitely looping trying to complete the task.